# Property cannot be found while getting image creation date

Tags: c#

I am getting an image creation date from images. I've notice that some of the images throws me `Property cannot be found.` error while the same code works on other images.

For ex,
I have tested my code on around 40 images where I didn't find any issue but now I am testing the same code on different set of images and all of these images are throwing this error.

Code:

```
private DateTime GetDateTakenFromImage(string path)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (Image myImage = Image.FromStream(fs, false, false))
    {
        PropertyItem propItem = myImage.GetPropertyItem(36867);//Throws error here
        string dateTaken = new Regex(":").Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItem.Value), "-", 2);
        return DateTime.Parse(dateTaken);
    }
}
```

I've checked image properties for working and non working images but I don't see any difference.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If this is jpeg EXIF information I'd look for EXIF reading code.

Answer (score 2):

The property doesn't always exist. Check first with something along the lines of:

```
if (myImage.PropertyIdList.Any(p => p == 36867))
```

Comment: In that case, how can I get image creation date? With this condition it will come out of the loop. If there is a way then can you please provide me a sample code?

Comment: If 36867 is null, you _can´t_ get the original image creation date.